# Is git push --mirror sufficient as a backup for repository that is used with git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

I would like to create a backup of a git repository that I use for tracking a svn repository (with git-svn). Can I use git push --mirror for that purpose or would I lose any git-svn related information when I needed to restore the backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible `git push` or `git bundle` do not include svn metadata.

But according to [`git svn` intro](http://www.vilain.net/talks/git-svn/intro.html#howto-track-rebuildmeta), you could then try and restore those svn metadata.
(disclaimer: not tested directly)

> **Rebuilding git-svn metadata**

If you copied the repository from somewhere else (eg, from `repo.utsl.gen.nz`) via `git-clone`, or if you just blew it away, then you won't have any SVN metadata - just commits.
In that case, you need to rebuild your SVN metadata, for instance, for just keeping trunk up to date - `git-svn` will rebuild its metadata when you run `git-svn fetch`.

```
$ git update-ref refs/remotes/trunk origin/svn/trunk
$ git svn init https://svn.perl.org/parrot/trunk
Using higher level of URL: https://svn.perl.org/parrot/trunk => https://svn.perl.org/parrot
$ git svn fetch
Rebuilding .git/svn/git-svn/.rev_db.d31e2699-5ff4-0310-a27c-f18f2fbe73fe ...
r17220 = 78ad11bf2f61b35e1cb32a978ab546d198be8a2e
r17219 = 605264b06d84670ec402d7a7a21c0016cae3a928
r17218 = a8ceba9c503d2be8e8e69a3df454017322906cf5
...
```

> The key thing to remember with rebuilding `git-svn` metadata is to make the refs look just like they would look from a fresh import; you can do this using `git update-ref` as above, by copying refs files around inside `.git/refs/`, or using `git pack-refs` then editing `.git/packed-refs`.
>   To test that you got it right, use `git show-ref` - perhaps compare with a fresh SVN `HEAD` clone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The git update-ref gives me the message: "fatal: origin/svn/trunk: not a valid SHA1", but git show-ref lists refs/remotes/trunk for the git repo mirror. Can I skip the update-ref then?

Comment: I had better results with `git update-ref refs/remotes/trunk origin/master` _after_ the `git svn init`.

But, unlike the example above, I had used `git svn init` with the -t/-b options which set up tags and branches too, so I also had to set up the refs for each of the tags.  (Obtained by running `git show-ref` on the original git-svn clone.)